# Facebook graph API: albums returns no data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, get

Facebook Graph API - likes returns me an empty set
When I try to get my albums on Facebook Graph API, it returns me an empty set:

```
{
   "data": [
   ]
}
```

i have added all the permissions as per the facebook graph API documentation for albums. Any idea of what i am doing wrong? I need to find the albums associated to a user and then list all the photos for each of the albums.

[image]

[image]

**update:**; i want to add that if I just try to get my basic information(name, id), the call works just fine.

[image]

Comment: Is the ID for a user or a page? Is the access token a user or page access token?

Comment: The id is for a user(me).The access token is the user access token.

Comment: Click on the "i" on the blue circle before the access token, and check what scopes that shows.

Comment: @thank you CBroe, your input helps me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using the user_id from the "i" on the blue circle before the access token
and using that in the user_id token field in the "get" request textfield.

[image]

[image]

i hope this helps someone.

Comment: Ah, so you were using the wrong user id then, one that does not belong to your app/the token. You should just use `/me` instead of an actual id - that is a shortcut to who-/whatever (user, page) the current token belongs to.

Comment: I made sure that I'm giving the permission to access user_photos but I get empty array, do you know why?